# Javascript: Remove white space of output array in browser console

Tags: javascript

Is there any method to remove unnecessary spaces of output array. When I run the code there is space in between comma and integer and also integer and bracket.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(arr);
```

**output**

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

**desire output**

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: No there isn't. Basically the console pretty-prints the array, which leads to spaces, but that's just a visual. In reality, you can't see if array is stored with spaces or without spaces.

Comment: `console.log` gave no functionally beside for display purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) or [console.log](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args) is  a basic tool function which have very defined behavior that you can't change.

The only thing you can do is to use a trick. `console.log` handle differently the `string` and the `arrays`, so you can transform your array before to display it.

Moreover they didn't made it possible to influence the display because there is no purpose to it. What are you trying to achieve using `console.log` in your app?

---

`console.log` had been created in order to display debug messages, not to display data to regular users.

For example in `node.js`, in order to display data to your user in console, use of :

```
process.stdout.write(your_string_in_your_own_format);
```

---

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

// Basic array
console.log(arr);

// Transform the arr into a string
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```