# Remove "the space" in the console.log?

Tags: javascript

Do think you that it possible to remove the space in the console.log ?

For example on this code

```
for(var i=0; i<3 ; i++){
    console.log("-");
}
```

I would like to display my dashes on a line.

```
-
-
-
```

By searching on StackOverFlow below, there is no solution visibly ?

[Javascript: Remove white space of output array in browser console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640052/javascript-remove-white-space-of-output-array-in-browser-console)

Comment: Why not just append to a string in the loop and log it after the loop? Seems easier than messing with how the console works.

Comment: @VLAZ: It's true, I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log within the loop, then you are issuing multiple `console.log()` commands and each will be on its own line.

If you record the value and concatenate that to a string, then you can log after the loop with one command.

```js
let result = "";
for(var i=0; i<3 ; i++){
  result += "-";
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

No.  The console is meant for output debugging only, and how it's presented is handled by the debugging tools.  At best you can do this:

```
const line = [];
for(var i=0; i<3 ; i++){
  line.push('-');
}

console.log(line.join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if it is very important situation for you, you may write that way in case:

```
let str = '';
let x = 3;
let i = 0;
while(i<x){
  str+='-';
  if(str.length===x){
    console.log(str);
  }
  i++;
}
```

But I would not recommend to type such inefficient way just for displaying in console. If you want to test inline console, use node.js with stdin and stdout.